# What is the most optimized way of creating a ray tracer?

Tags: optimization, raytracing

Currently, I am working with a ray tracer that takes an iterative approach towards developing the scenes. My goal is to turn it into a recursive ray tracer.

At the moment, I have a ray tracer defined to do the following operation to create the bitmap it is stored in:

```
int WIDTH = 640;
int HEIGHT = 640;
BMP Image(WIDTH, HEIGHT); // create new bitmap

// Slightly shoot rays left of right camera direction
    double xAMT, yAMT;
    */

    Color blue(0.1, 0.61, 0.76, 0);
    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {

            if (WIDTH > HEIGHT) {
                xAMT = ((x + 0.5) / WIDTH) * aspectRatio - (((WIDTH - HEIGHT) / (double)HEIGHT) / 2);
                yAMT = ((HEIGHT - y) + 0.5) / HEIGHT;
            }
            else if (HEIGHT > WIDTH) {
                xAMT = (x + 0.5) / WIDTH;
                yAMT = (((HEIGHT - y) + 0.5) / HEIGHT) / aspectRatio - (((HEIGHT - WIDTH) / (double)WIDTH) / 2);
            }
            else {
                xAMT = (x + 0.5) / WIDTH;
                yAMT = ((HEIGHT - y) + 0.5) / HEIGHT;
            }
            ..... // calculate intersections, shading, reflectiveness.... etc
           Image.setPixel(x, y, blue); // this is here just as an example
      }
}
```

Is there another approach to calculating the reflective and refractive child rays outside the double for-loop?
Are the for-loops necessary? // yes because of the bitmap?
What approaches can be taken to minimize/optimize an iterative ray tracer?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear as currently written. In general though, tracing a ray is a simple function of a ray (a start point and a vector direction) and a scene. It can be implemented largely independently of the code that is responsible for generating primary rays and can be called recursively to generate secondary rays (reflections, shadows, GI bounces, etc.). Recursive ray tracers are arguably the simplest to write but not necessarily the most efficient approach.

Comment: To clarify a little, you can treat the generation of primary rays as a largely independent problem from the tracing of rays. You may in fact want to generate multiple primary rays per pixel for example. Ray tracing is highly parallelizable so it can often make sense to split up your primary ray generation into batches and process those batches in parallel across multiple cores.